# mysql query to establish booked walks still available

Tags: mysql

I need some support with a query.  Basically I have a database for a Walks company.  The tables are as follows, Guides - Walks - Participants - Programme - Booking and GuideWalk, which is a linking table.

I need to do a query that would give output data that would tell me for each walk, how many places there are, how many have booked and how many are available.

Any help would be appreciated.

The tables are as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `Participant` (
  `part_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `part_sname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `part_fname` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `part_phone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `part_email` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `part_status` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`part_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=73 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `Booking` (
  `bookprog_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `part_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bookprog_id`,`part_id`),
  KEY `part_id_idx` (`part_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `bookprog` FOREIGN KEY (`bookprog_id`) REFERENCES `Programme` (`prog_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `part_id` FOREIGN KEY (`part_id`) REFERENCES `Participant` (`part_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `Guide` (
  `guide_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `guide_fname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `guide_sname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `guide_address1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `guide_address2` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `guide_town` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `guide_pcode` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `guide_email` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `guide_mphone` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`guide_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=274 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `GuideWalk` (
  `guide_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prog_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`guide_id`,`prog_id`),
  KEY `prog_id_idx` (`prog_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `prog_id` FOREIGN KEY (`prog_id`) REFERENCES `Programme` (`prog_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `guide_id` FOREIGN KEY (`guide_id`) REFERENCES `Guide` (`guide_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `Programme` (
  `prog_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pwalk_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prog_date` date NOT NULL,
  `prog_stime` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `prog_max` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`prog_id`),
  KEY `pwalk_id_idx` (`pwalk_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `pwalk_id` FOREIGN KEY (`pwalk_id`) REFERENCES `Walk` (`walk_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `Walk` (
  `walk_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `walk_title` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `walk_dur` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `walk_spoint` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `walk_fpoint` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `walk_desc` text NOT NULL,
  `walkleader_1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `walkleader_2` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`walk_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have managed to output every day and how many places are available with this query

```
SELECT prog_max AS 'Places', prog_date AS 'Day'
FROM  Programme
WHERE prog_date BETWEEN '2014-07-20' AND '2014-08-03'
```

I really haven't a clue on how to progress from here

Solution

```
SELECT walk_title, DAYNAME(prog_date) AS 'Day', DATE_FORMAT(prog_date, '%D %M %Y') AS 'Date', 
prog_stime AS 'Start Time', walk_spoint AS 'Meet At', walkleader_1 AS 'Guide 1', 
walkleader_2 AS 'Guide 2', Booking.bookprog_id AS 'Booked', ABS(Programme.prog_id -Programme.prog_max) AS'Available', 
prog_max AS 'Places'
FROM Walk, Programme
INNER JOIN Booking
ON bookprog_id=prog_id
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: What query has been tried? How did (or didn't) it work?

Comment: I am not even sure where to start if I am honest, that is why I was looking some suggestions

Comment: I would start by learning SQL queries - this includes joins. There are many tutorials online.

Comment: Yes been watching some tutorials, I am 100% sure the solution is in joins.  Thought I would pick some brains here first.

Comment: Good job, I'm glad to here that! :)

Comment: Solution I needed SELECT walk_title, DAYNAME(prog_date) AS 'Day', DATE_FORMAT(prog_date, '%D %M %Y') AS 'Date', 
prog_stime AS 'Start Time', walk_spoint AS 'Meet At', walkleader_1 AS 'Guide 1', 
walkleader_2 AS 'Guide 2', Booking.bookprog_id AS 'Booked', ABS(Programme.prog_id -Programme.prog_max) AS'Available', 
prog_max AS 'Places'
FROM Walk, Programme
INNER JOIN Booking
ON bookprog_id=prog_id
LIMIT 10

Comment: By _Solution_, do you mean to say that you solved your issue? If so, you should post the solution as an answer below. When the timeout has expired, you may mark it as accepted to indicate to others that it is solved.

Comment: Will post as soon as I can. Thanks :)

Comment: Tip: Do not mix implicit and explicit join styles; you've not specified how  walks relate to programmes; and LIMIT without ORDER BY is meaningless.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT walk_title, DAYNAME(prog_date) AS 'Day', DATE_FORMAT(prog_date, '%D %M %Y') AS 'Date', 
prog_stime AS 'Start Time', walk_spoint AS 'Meet At', walkleader_1 AS 'Guide 1', 
walkleader_2 AS 'Guide 2', Booking.bookprog_id AS 'Booked', ABS(Programme.prog_id -Programme.prog_max) AS'Available', 
prog_max AS 'Places'
FROM Walk, Programme
INNER JOIN Booking
ON bookprog_id=prog_id
LIMIT 10